# Why are eddy currents round?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why does the current produced in a metallic conductor follow a circular path specifically during electromagnetic induction?

Is it true that a circle of all geometrical shapes encloses the least perimeter, and hence the current follows a circular path?(as currents flow in the least resistive path)

Comment: You are right with your statement "it is true that a circle of all geometrical shapes encloses the least perimeter.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, I think one needs to look at Faraday's Law in its general form, so I apologize if this mathematics is at a higher level than your current work.  I'll try make the language conceptually accessible.

The [Maxwell-Faraday Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell%E2%80%93Faraday_equation) within Maxwell's Equations is:
$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}\,.
$$
We can integrate the flux of this equation through an arbitrary two-dimensional surface, $S$, to obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_S \left(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}\right) \cdot \hat{n}  \,\, dA & = - \int_S  \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \hat{n} \,\, dA\\
\oint_{\partial S} \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{r} &=  - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \int_S \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \, dA \right]
\end{align}
$$
where I've used Stoke's theorem on the left-hand side, $\partial S$ represents the boundary curve of the surface $S$ (so the integral, $\oint$, is over a closed curve, $C = \partial S$), and the term in brackets on the right-hand side is the flux of the magnetic field through the surface $S$.

This law is then paraphrased in elementary physics as: $\mathcal{E}_\text{ind} = - \frac{d \Phi_B}{dt}$, where the integral of the electric field over a closed loop is a voltage/emf. If you take the curve $C$ to be a circle and the magnetic field to be changing in time but *uniform* over that circular area and directed perpendicular to it, then the rather complicated-looking integral yields a simple calculation:
$$
|\Delta V_\text{loop}| = \frac{d B(t)}{dt} A_\text{loop} = \frac{d B(t)}{dt} \, \pi R_\text{loop}^2
$$
and you could place a circular loop of wire on that curve (with resistance $R$, such that $\Delta V = I R$) to get an induced current given by:
$$
I_\text{ind} = \frac{d B(t)}{dt} \frac{\pi R_\text{loop}^2}{R}
$$

For eddy currents, any/all closed loops through the metal (with changing magnetic field through their surface) could serve as the imagined curve over which to integrate the electric field, and all could carry induced current.  They need not be circular.

To find the net eddy current in a solid metal cylinder, one should probably do something like: (1) find the electric field at loops of all radius (choose $C$ to be circles of every increasing radius), using Faraday's law, above; (2) determine the current *density* from that electric field, $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$ (where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the metal); and (3) integrate the total current as $I = \int \vec{J} \cdot \hat{n} \, dA$.